# Possible code optimizations for a spreadsheet cell loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, optimization

I am attempting to iterate over multiple cells of a spreadsheet and, if they meet a set of requirements, I would like to change their background color and change their text. Problem is, if it finds multiple of these cells that have this specific setting, it takes a long time as it needs to update each one of those manually. The reason I do not have it update an entire range is because some of the cells in the middle are reserved for another purpose. Here is the code I have written so far, how could I optimize it for it to run faster?

```
["File1","File2","File3"].forEach(function(sheet) {
   spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheet), true);
    for(i=10;i<99;i++) {
      let cell = spreadsheet.getRange("J"+i);
      if (cell.getBackground() == "#00ff00") {
        cell.setBackground('#ea4335')
        cell.clearContent();
      } else if(cell.getBackground() == "#ea4335" && cell.getValue().toString().length > 0) {
        cell.clearContent();
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Using a for loop to get and set cell by cell can be very slow if you have a tall column.Try using a range for the whole column, then use the get methods to get value and formatting, then set the whole range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetNames = ["File1","File2","File3"]; // Please set your sheet names.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheetNames.forEach(sheetName => {
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    const range = sheet.getRange("J10:J98");
    const values = range.getDisplayValues();
    const backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();
    const { ranges1, ranges2 } = backgrounds.reduce((o, [j], i) => {
      if (j == "#00ff00") {
        o.ranges1.push(`J${i + 10}`);
        o.ranges2.push(`J${i + 10}`);
      } else if (j == "#ea4335" && values[i][0]) {
        o.ranges2.push(`J${i + 10}`);
      }
      return o;
    }, { ranges1: [], ranges2: [] });
    if (ranges1.length > 0) sheet.getRangeList(ranges1).setBackground("#ea4335");
    if (ranges2.length > 0) sheet.getRangeList(ranges2).clearContent();
  });
}
```

- In this modification, as a simple modification, in order to reduce the process cost of your script, RangeList is used.

#### Note:

- In this modified script, it supposes that your showing script works fine. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [setBackground(color) of Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#setBackground(String))
- [clearContent() of Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#clearcontent)

Comment: I receive an error as follows:
``Exception: Ranges must have at least one range.``
This error is on line ``sheet.getRangeList(ranges1).setBackground("#ea4335");``

Comment: @779804 Thank you for replying. About `Exception: Ranges must have at least one range. This error is on line sheet.getRangeList(ranges1).setBackground("#ea4335");`, I apologize for the inconvenience. From the error, I guessed that in your situation, the sheets without including the ranges of "J10:J98" might be included. Although I'm not sure whether my guess is correct, I updated my answer. Please confirm it. If that was not the direct solution to your current issue, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: That worked. The problem was that not all sheets had a modified background/text in the J column, and the ranges array was empty. Regardless, thank you!